# Complete missing sequence in array with zeros in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array:

```js
const arr = [
  [5, 0.2],
  [7, 0.6],
  [8, 0.3],
  [10, 0.4]
];

console.log(arr)
```

I need to ensure that the first element of the array is a sequence from 5 to 10:

`[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

In the above example, these numbers within the sequence are missing:

`[6, 9]`

If they are missing, I need to include them with zeros:

```js
const expectedResult = [
  [5, 0.2],
  [6, 0],
  [7, 0.6],
  [8, 0.3],
  [9, 0],
  [10, 0.4]
];

console.log(expectedResult)
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Is the sequence range known?

Comment: yes, from 5 to 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could map the missing parts with a closure over the actual index of the given array.

```js
const
    array = [[5, 0.2], [7, 0.6], [8, 0.3], [10, 0.4]],
    result = Array.from(
        { length: 6 },
        (i => (_, j) => array[i]?.[0] === j + 5 ? array[i++] : [j + 5, 0])(0)
    );

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @thgaskell, no, because found, it should increment to get the next element in the next loop.